# Net Screen Remote RDP not working but vpn is

Tags: vpn, rdp, connection, netscreen

I have a problem regarding a connection with Netscreen-remote. First of all, to install the program I had to create a VM of XP x32b because of compatibility issues. Once it is installed, I imported the security policy created by the host. When I click connect, it says Successfully connected to (target). But I cannot do a RDP to the server or even ping it. When I do the command ipconfig it dosen't give me the new IP address that I should get. This use to work perfectly a week before. I changed nothing on my side and the host told me he didn't change anything either. I did check if my VM was using the correct network adapter of my physical machine but it is.

Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [Junos Pulse][1] which works fine under vista and windows 7. it is the same as the nescreen remote.

also, to help you troubleshoot the issue, it would be grate if you could uplodad the connection logs.

> 

- Logs from the NetScreen-Remote Client:

  1. Export the NetScreen-Remote's .SPD file: 1.At the Security Policy Editor, click on File -> Export Security Policy. This will display the Export Policy To... window.
  2. Save the policy to the PC's hard drive by naming the file and selecting a location to save it. Make sure the policy is unlocked.
  3. Click Export.
- Save the Log Viewer file:

  1. Right click on the NS-Remote's icon in the PC's System Tray.
  2. Left click on Log Viewer
  3. Click on Save Log. This will bring up the Save As window.
  4. Give the file a name, leaving the extension as .log, and save it to the PC's hard drive.

  [1]: http://www.juniper.net/us/en/products-services/software/junos-platform/junos-pulse/"Junos Pulse"

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I already checked the log file and it never says anything about an error during the connection. I did check the registry to see if everything change the same as the policy that I received from the host but everything is the same.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I just realized I hadn't close this question. The answer is that Netscreen remote and CheckPoint are not compatible, you have to close the Check point program to be able to use Netscreen remote. Thank you.